# Copy Job Status The error was: Fetch to http://xxxyyyzzz.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api failed with status 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working in google app engine for past 3 days. I am struck with a issue where i cannot "`Datastore Admin: Copy to Another App`". When I try to copy entities it give me this error 
    "`Copy Job Status`". There was a problem kicking off the jobs. The error was:

```
Fetch to http://xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api failed with status 404".
```

I have enabled Datastore admin. I have made modifications in `app.yaml` file and `appengine_config.py` file. Updated `appcfg.py` in command prompt.

Still i am not able to copy entites from one application to another.

What could be the issue I am facing. Can someone please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled remote_api in builtins section of app.yaml

Comment: s i have enabled remote_api in builtins section of app.yaml

Comment: I have the same problem, I have enabled `builtins:- remote_api: on`, but still not working. Did you ever figure out what your problem was with that?